# Escape substituted path in SCons

Tags: scons

In this piece of code from Wesnoth build the $TESTFILE variable is substituted with the given path. But on Windows path becomes invalid, because by default SCons `subst()` doesn't escape backslashes in paths. Is there a way to do this - get absolute filename for SCons File node with escaped backslashes? Or escape backslashes while substituting?

```
test_program = '''
    #include <SDL_mixer.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        Mix_Music* music = Mix_LoadMUS("$TESTFILE");
        if (music == NULL) {
            exit(1);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
\n
'''
print Environment(TESTFILE = File("data/core/music/main_menu.ogg").rfile().abspath). \
          subst(test_program)
```

The output:

```
 #include <SDL_mixer.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
     Mix_Music* music = Mix_LoadMUS("E:\wesnoth\scons\data\core\music\main_menu.ogg");
     if (music == NULL) {
         exit(1);
     }
     exit(0);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [os.path.normpath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) from python 2.7 docs..?

> os.path.normpath(path)
>
> Normalize a pathname by collapsing redundant
> separators and up-level references so that A//B, A/B/, A/./B and
> A/foo/../B all become A/B. This string manipulation may change the
> meaning of a path that contains symbolic links. On Windows, it
> converts forward slashes to backward slashes. To normalize case, use
> normcase().

Comment: No, normpath doesn't help here.

Comment: `os.path.normpath(File("data/core/music/main_menu.ogg").rfile().abspath)` doesn't help.

Comment: What does that produce?

Comment: The same `E:\wesnoth\scons\data\core\music\main_menu.ogg` because it is "printed" string.

Comment: I just tried using ${TESTFILE.posix} in the above sample code. And it fails. Which suprised me.  I'm going to bring the discussion to the mailing list.  I'll report back when I have a simpler functional solution.

Answer (score 0):

After cloning the Wesnoth repo and inspecting the actual build files, I found that the problem you describe happens in the context of configuration. This doesn't get clear in your original question, and renders my first try of an answer useless (using the `Substfile` builder, see history).
As far as I know, there is currently no option built into SCons to handle the double-backslashing you're looking for. The cleanest way I can think of right now would be to clone the method `SConf.SConfBase.TryRun` (e.g. name it `TryRunWithArgs`), make it accept additional program arguments, add it to the configure context with `AddTest()` and then rewrite the test program such that it accepts the filename as first argument.

Comment: Fixed it with extra slashery https://github.com/wesnoth/wesnoth/commit/c001f661f0810c78df3c3ea1e57c54d8a9c1169e